# JPA - @OneToOne relation on non-primary-key field not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I have a Spring Data JPA backend using Hibernate as the ORM implementation.

This is the model:

```
 __________     _________________________
 |Person  |     |MailConfig             |
 |________|     |_______________________|
 | id PK  |     | uid PK-FK(Person.uid) |
 | uid    |     | ...                   |
 | ...    |     |                       | 
 |________|     |_______________________|

@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class PersonEntity{

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String uid;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="id", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private MailConfigEntity mailConfigNotes;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="MailConfig")
public class MailConfigEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="uid", table="Person", referencedColumnName="uid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PersonEntity id;

    ...
}
```

Person table is joined with MailConfig table through a field that is not Person's primary key. When I load an entity using `personDAO.findOne(id)` I can see the join in the query is performed against person.id instead of person.uid (`on personent0_.id=mailconfig2_.uid`). Any idea why this isn't working?

Query log:

```
    select
        personent0_.id as id8_2_,
        personent0_.uid as uid8_2_,
        mailconfig2_.uid as uid5_1_
    from
        Person personent0_ 
    left outer join
        mailconfig mailconfig2_ 
            on personent0_.id=mailconfig2_.uid 
    where
        personent0_.id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, check if this is a foreign key

> There are three cases for one-to-one associations: either the
>   associated entities share the same primary keys values, a foreign key
>   is held by one of the entities (note that this FK column in the
>   database should be constrained unique to simulate one-to-one
>   multiplicity), or a association table is used to store the link
>   between the 2 entities (a unique constraint has to be defined on each
>   fk to ensure the one to one multiplicity).

Also the JoinColumn should be on the owner side of the relationship

Comment: So... you mean that OneToOne associations don't support joining on non-primary-keys?

Comment: @WornOutSoles - yes i believe so, you can check the documentation regarding oneToOne annotation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/

Comment: I gotta disagree, it seems to be supported. From the documentation you linked, section 2.2.5.1. One-to-one: `Note that when using referencedColumnName to a non primary key column, the associated class has to be Serializable. Also note that the referencedColumnName to a non primary key column has to be mapped to a property having a single column (other cases might not work).`