# Hibernate - mapping composite relations to non-primary keys

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I have to map a large enterprise database schema. As a number of legacy applications are depending on that schema I can't change it from composite keys to surrogate keys (other than using views with instead-of triggers for ~70% of database objects) which led me to a number of issues I don't know how to overcome.

1. How to map tables that have a surrogate (primary, auto-increment) key and a composite unique key to which a number of tables form a many-to-one relation over the surrogate key, and at the same time a number of legacy tables relate over the composite unique?
2. What to do when several relationships over composite keys share the same component (Naselja: Korisnik/Opcina, Korisnik/Grad)? 
   Hibernate tells me I can't use the same column (Korisnik) twice, unless I add 'updatable = false, insertable = false' to the @JoinColumn annotation. Yet when I do that, I get the message that all components of the relation have to have the same settings for insertable and updatable. How do I ever update or insert the second relation then?
3. Inserting a row into 'Ulice' table will give me a error "org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(Korisnik, Naselje) of lc.data.hibernate.Ulice.naselja referencing lc.data.hibernate.Naselja not mapped to a single property" unless in 'Naselja' table I explicitly add a many-to-one relation to 'Korisnici' table in the model, which doesn't reflect the actual database schema.

From what I've read so far [JPA doesn't support relationships to non-primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818373/does-the-jpa-specification-allow-references-to-non-primary-key-columns), but [people still do it](http://www.kawoolutions.com/Technology/JPA,_Hibernate,_and_Co./Relationships_to_Non-Primary_Key_Columns). Also my second problem [might be solved with Hibernate 5](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6221), but I'm hoping for some good advice what route to take here.

Test model, database scripts and projects:

---

[image: Database schema MSSQL]

[MSSQL create database scripts](http://pastebin.com/G9qL6HbJ)

[Java NetBeans example projects](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxIzMpeayz9nWm1YalZhTllQdjQ)

Comment: One idea I had, is putting updatable=false, insertable=false on all Hibernate relations, explicitly mapping every field in the table and handling the relations manually... It works, but it seems very wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
- map the autoincrementing columns as primary key
- create classes for the compositeid and map the many-to-one with property-ref

```
    <component name="compIdProperty" unique="true">
      <property column="naselje" />
      <many-to-one column="korisnik" class="Korisnik"/>
    </component>

    <many-to-one name="Naselja" property-ref="compIdProperty">
      <column name="naselje" />
      <column name="korisnik" />
    </many-to-one>
```

2) AFAIK it is not possible at all using hibernate

only possible way i see is to map (Grad, Opcina) as properties and manage the association yourself

3) since this is a legacy schema i would go the compromise of adding the many-to-one and also map the many-to-one to Korisnik in Opcine and Gradovi

Comment: So if I manage associations manually that way, are there any Hibernate gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: on the things Hibernate does not know of, it can not interfere.

Comment: I've now found that all fetching is forced to eager when mapped like this; Any way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: other than don't mapping the association and manage by hand no because NH needs the identity of the referenced object which is not present when using property-ref