# JPA mapping with relationship on same entity (category, child categories and parent category)

Tags: java, jpa, recursion, jpa-2.0

I am trying to solve a problem regarding category with child categories and parent category on same entity. My database is already set and I can't change it. So, I have mapped my entity this way:

```
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3432724244623524272L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "key", nullable = false)
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "category_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_key", referencedColumnName = "key")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Category> childCategories;

    //getters and setters ommited
}
```

Note, that the child categories and parent category is not mapped using the ID attribute, but the "key" attribute. This "key" is not a FK. When JPA is trying to get the data, my application crash. But this crash is look like an infinite loop. No exception is thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might be interested in this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818373/does-the-jpa-specification-allow-references-to-non-primary-key-columns

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I'd say do a trial run, first setting fetch to  FetchType.LAZY.

Answer (score 1):

Possible infinite loop :

1. You load an object A
2. This object has a child B, which is loaded as well since you use `FetchType.EAGER`
3. B has a parent, which is A, which is loaded again
4. etc.

Try using `FetchType.LAZY`.