# Can I map a relationship inJPA with a unique target that is not the id?

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I'd like to be able to use the dot notation to get from one entity to another.

Let's say I have a table `Users`:

```
id  username   acronym
-----------------------
 1  john       NASA
```

And a table `Institutions`:

```
id  instname       acronym
---------------------------
 9  Natl. Air...   NASA
```

For historical reasons, the Users table does not contain a reference to the Institution id, but the acronym is unique.

Is there any possibility to dot my way from the entity for John to the name of NASA as in `john.getInstitution().InstName()`? I'd like to avoid having to run a query through the entity manager.

Comment: I think you should re think your data structure. If acronym is unique, you should declare acronym is foreign key. If acronym is not unique, you cannot map a relationship.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't (easily) make changes to the model. But would that help? If it's declared a foreign key, doesn't it have to be the primary key in the target table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually tried it?

As far as I can see then, depending on your JPA provider, the following mappings may or not be supported.

```
@Entity
public class Institution{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution")
    private Set<User> users;
}

@Entity
public class User {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "acronym", referencedColumName = "acronym")
    private Institution institution;

}
```

Failing this, the other possibility is to create a database view based on the following and map your User entity to this.

```
select 
    u.id, u.username, i.id as institution_id
from 
    users u
inner join 
    institutions i on u.acronym = i.acronym
```

Entity with 'proper' FK mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vw_users")
public class User {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id")
    private Institution institution;

}
```

Comment: That's true, if you use Hibernate as your JPA provider it just works. But I like your view suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ["no, you can't"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818373/does-the-jpa-specification-allow-references-to-non-primary-key-columns), apparently: "[T]he JPA spec doesn't allow relationships/FKs to non-PK columns at all"