# @OneToOne mapping for non key columns

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I am working on using Hibernate for an existing legacy schema (I cannot update it) and there is a curious case:

**Table User:**

1. db_id PK
2. user_id (Unique constraint)
3. ... other columns

**Table Address**

1. db_id PK
2. user_id (Unique constraint)
3. ... usual address columns

These have a one-one relationship. I am creating following `@Entity` annotated classes.

```
class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID dbId;

    private String userId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private AddressEntity address;
}
```

```
class AddressEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID dbId;

    private String userId;

    @OneToOne
    private UserEntity user;
}
```

Hibernate thinks this is a duplicate column definition which is reasonable. However since in the Address table I do not have user_id as FK or PK I am not sure how to communicate this to Hibernate. I have tried to search for a similar but no success so any advise will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATED

Probably there are better ways to accomplish this, like using a `@NaturalId`, but I cannot get it work with Hibernate 5.2.12.Final.

However, `@JoinFormula` to the rescue:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "DB_ID", length = 36)
    private UUID dbId;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinFormula("(select x.DB_ID from T_ADDRESS x where x.USER_ID=USER_ID)")
    private AddressEntity address;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s: dbId=%s, userId=%s, address=%s",
            getClass().getSimpleName(),
            dbId,
            userId,
            address != null ? address.getDbId() : null);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ADDRESS")
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name = "DB_ID", length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private UUID dbId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
    private UserEntity user;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s: dbId=%s, user=%s",
            getClass().getSimpleName(),
            dbId,
            user != null ? user.getDbId() : null);
    }
}
```

Tested it with MySQL8 using:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_user` (
  `DB_ID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DB_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_kvueux8cmkdekeqhrs7pumkwi` (`USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `t_address` (
  `DB_ID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DB_ID`),
  KEY `FK1s9gxk3we3yq11hjw5hp7ahp5` (`USER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1s9gxk3we3yq11hjw5hp7ahp5` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

with this quick'n'dirty launcher:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test_hibernate");
        try
        {
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            try
            {
                EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
                transaction.begin();

                try
                {
                    UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
                    user.setDbId(UUID.randomUUID());
                    user.setUserId("user_" + System.nanoTime());

                    em.persist(user);


                    AddressEntity address = new AddressEntity();
                    address.setDbId(UUID.randomUUID());

                    address.setUser(user);
                    user.setAddress(address);

                    em.persist(address);

                    transaction.commit();

                    System.out.println("persisted user: " + user);
                    System.out.println("persisted address: " + address);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    transaction.rollback();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                em.close();
            }


            EntityManager em2 = emf.createEntityManager();
            try
            {
                List<UserEntity> userList = em2.createQuery("select x from UserEntity x", UserEntity.class).getResultList();
                userList.forEach(x -> System.out.println("loaded user: " + x));

                List<AddressEntity> addressList = em2.createQuery("select x from AddressEntity x", AddressEntity.class).getResultList();
                addressList.forEach(x -> System.out.println("loaded address: " + x));
            }
            finally
            {
                em2.close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            emf.close();
        }

        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

that produced these results:

```
persisted user: UserEntity: dbId=a22db668-eda0-4de1-83ae-98a7cd8738bd, userId=user_789235935853200, address=c17c0c28-603e-4961-90b0-16232346e47b
persisted address: AddressEntity: dbId=c17c0c28-603e-4961-90b0-16232346e47b, user=a22db668-eda0-4de1-83ae-98a7cd8738bd

loaded user: UserEntity: dbId=a22db668-eda0-4de1-83ae-98a7cd8738bd, userId=user_789235935853200, address=c17c0c28-603e-4961-90b0-16232346e47b
loaded address: AddressEntity: dbId=c17c0c28-603e-4961-90b0-16232346e47b, user=a22db668-eda0-4de1-83ae-98a7cd8738bd
```

Comment: Thanks, this does not work. In this case the "owning" side is ambiguous. Also looks like maybe this is not supported at all (not very clear) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818373/does-the-jpa-specification-allow-references-to-non-primary-key-columns

Comment: You're right, I understimated that the relation is not based on the PK. I supposed Hibernate was smart enough to figure it with the proper mapping, but it's not the case. Please see the update. However this is the first idea that I came up with and, even if it works, probably there are better solutions, this is just a workaround.

Comment: Thanks maybe will get time to look in the future. For now I'm keeping them as entities with no relationship and just dealing with necessary "join" in code. Likely I will just add FK in future and have a standard mapping! Thanks for taking the time to investigate Michele.

Answer (score 0):

one-one relationship define like:

```
class UserEntity {
  ....

  @Column(length = 20)
  private String userId;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private AddressEntity address;

}

class AddressEntity {
  ....

  @Column(length = 20)
  private String userId;

  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for using `@OneToOne` relations in both of entities, when you need to use it in non exist column side, you have to map it to corresponding field, so you can use it like it:

```
class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID dbId;

    private String userId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private AddressEntity address;
}

class AddressEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID dbId;

    private String userId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private UserEntity user;
}
```