# Exception when using multiple relationships (one-to-one and one-to-many) in one entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

This is the **PostgreSQL** database: column product(name) is referenced by column thumbnail(product_name) and product_image(product_name). Column product_image(image_url) is referenced by thumbnail(thumbnail).

[image: database]

Those 3 codes under are 3 entities

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank(message = "please fill in name")
    @Length(max = 255, message = "too long")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @NotBlank(message = "please select category")
    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String category_name;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<ProductImage> productImages;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product_name")
    private Thumbnail thumbnail;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_image")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ProductImage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String url;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
    private Product product;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "thumbnail")
    private Thumbnail thumbnail;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "thumbnail")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Thumbnail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "thumbnail", referencedColumnName = "image_url")
    private ProductImage thumbnail;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
    private Product product_name;
}
```

This is the Controller

```java
@GetMapping("/product/{product}")
    public String product(Model model, @PathVariable String product) {
        Product result = productRepository.findByName("iphone X");
        List<ProductImage> productImageList = imageRepository.findAllByProduct(result);
        result.setProductImages(productImageList);
        model.addAttribute("product", result);
        return "product";
}
```

This is the template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>product detail</title>
    <style>
        *{
            white-space: pre-wrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>product images</p>
<img th:each="image : ${product.getProductImages()}" th:src="'https://d2md72j0ra7dia.cloudfront.net/' + ${image.getUrl()}" width="100">
<p th:text="'product name:' + ${product.getName()}"></p>
<p th:text="'product descrption:' + ${product.getDescription()}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

when findByName method is called, it generates this Exception

```java
2020-06-12 07:19:36.991 ERROR 39998 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.project.shopping_site.Entities.Product.name] by reflection for persistent property [com.project.shopping_site.Entities.Product#name] : 20; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String com.project.shopping_site.Entities.Product.name] by reflection for persistent property [com.project.shopping_site.Entities.Product#name] : 20] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.project.shopping_site.Entities.Product.name to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:419) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.generateHashCode(EntityUniqueKey.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.<init>(EntityUniqueKey.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:738) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1179) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1028) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1581) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.findByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.findByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.project.shopping_site.Controllers.UserController.product(UserController.java:117) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
```

**Notice**: this error only appears when I add those 2 codes

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "product_name")
    private Thumbnail thumbnail;
```

and

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "thumbnail")
    private Thumbnail thumbnail;
```

If I remove those 2 codes, the program works just fine.

[image: result]

**Notice 2**: if I findByName a non-exist name in database, then it won't generate any errors.

I don't understand what I did wrong, and cannot find anything on the internet.

Comment: Could you provide the data that we are suppose to see when you use the query with "iphone x"?

Comment: @Guardian i've just updated the Controller and thymeleaf template. the image is the result it generated to html file. Is that ok or would you like me to print the data in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA has never allowed you to create a relationship like this

[See the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818373/does-the-jpa-specification-allow-references-to-non-primary-key-columns)

Comment: Wow. Thank you, i fixed it. However, the one-to-many works just fine without primary key as the code above, why is there such inconsistence?

Comment: Not sure for now, looking for jpa mapping with non pk a proper documentation.